# splicing an array from objects resets the whole object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object

```
inputErrors:
value: Array(8)
0: "name"
1: "industry"
2: "address"
3: "crn"
4: "website"
5: "employeesNbr"
6: "phoneNumber"
7: "userRole"
```

if I get sent a param to a function called key which is basically either from name to userole, what statement can i use to the delete the whole value that contains that key?
I used
`inputErrors.value.splice(key);`

This reseted the whole object.
What i need is ill be sent a key of kind string which will either be {name,industry...}, and what i will want is delete its corresponding index. so for example if they key sent is address and delete address it becomes:

```
0: "name"
1: "industry"
3: "crn"
4: "website"
5: "employeesNbr"
6: "phoneNumber"
7: "userRole"


Thank you
```

Comment: You can use Array.filter(), which will remove your target element and return a new Array. Please refer to here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to preserve indexes to generate a sparse array, you can work directly with the object instead of using array methods (yes, arrays are objects in JavaScript).

```
delete inputErrors[inputErrors.indexOf('address')]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are okay with a new Array then you can use Array.filter().

If you want to modify the same array, then use findIndex to find the index of the key in the array then use

```
someArray.splice(x, 1); // to remove the element at index 'x'
```

Comment: this won't achieve `3: "crn"` as requested in the question